# Current path does not match path patterns error

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to Django and I've been following this page step-by-step: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/.
However, when I try to call the polls app using localhost:8000/polls, a page not found error shows up.

I don't have too much of an idea how to fix this, since I'm pretty new. I remember seeing how VS was complaining about the module admin not working but I resolved it by just reinstating the python interpreter.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPWMA.png); [URLS.py in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps11j.png); [URLS.py in polls app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDAnD.png); [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a11Cn.png)

I also tried to re=run the server and reloading VS but it didn't really help.

All of my modules match the one in the tutorial.

Comment: Check your urls.py (you should have two, one at the mysite/mysite level, then one in your polls app folder) for typos. If you can't see anything, post them and your error in the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.